# Why is my websocket server not serving my HTML page correctly?

Tags: node.js, html, websocket, server

I have created an instance of a web socket using NodeJS in a file called app.js and declared a listener on port 8080. However, when I run the command to start the connection- the connection is not being established and is not logging to console. I am trying to open a web socket connection and create a talking server. When I run my app.js- the createServer() function doesn't fire and "new connection" is not being logged. Are there more parameters that I need in order to open the connection? I am new to websockets; any help is appreciated.

Here is my app.js code:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket")
console.log("testing")

var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {
    console.log("New connection")
    conn.on("text", function (str) {
        console.log("Received "+str)
        conn.sendText(str.toUpperCase()+"!!!")
    })
    conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
        console.log("Connection closed")
    })
}).listen(8080);
```

Here is where I try to connect to the websocket in the client site. I would like to send the websocket whatever is inputted into the text box and then log the return string in the input tag.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
Result: <output type=text id="result0" value="" readonly></output>
</p>

<input type="text" onchange="connection.send(this.value); " />

<script>
    var connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/echo");
    connection.onmessage = function (event){
    document.getElementById("result0").value = event.data;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correctly ... just execute your server in terminal A

```
npm install -g nodejs-websocket  # if not installed 
node my_websocket.js
```

then save your client as file  browser_client.html
then inside same dir issue this to launch a httpd server in a new terminal B

```
npm install -g http-server # install an httpd server to render html file
http-server -c-1 -p 8888   # this launches the httpd
```

then open up a browser and point at link

```
http://localhost:8888/browser_client.html
```

and you will see in terminal A output

```
New connection
```

then in text box in browser enter some text

```
apples and oranges
```

which will appear back in terminal A as well as shown in browser